# Using the Google Maps API, how do you revert to full text if filtering doesn't work?

Tags: google-maps

With google maps you can search using "components". For example, if I want to search by postal code, I can do this:

```
components=postal_code:1234
```

Problem is, if the user provided the wrong postal code, and it was, for example, 1235, the result will return nothing, even though there is a small mistake on the users side.

Is there a way to tell google that if searching by components fails, that it must please carry on search as if though the postal code was not provided?